# Remove left padding of line numbers in less

Tags: less

If you toggle the `-N` switch within `less`, it displays line numbers. However, there seems to be an unnecessarily generous amount of padding added, even when the total lines is small. E.g. the output of `man less` with line numbers enabled is:

```
      1 LESS(1)
      2
      3 NAME
      4        less - opposite of more
      5 
      6 SYNOPSIS
      7        less -?
      8        less --help
      9        less -V
     10        less --version
     11        less [-[+]aABcCdeEfFgGiIJKLmMnNqQrRsSuUVwWX~]
...
    940       Version 487: 25 Oct 2016
```

Is there a way to control or reduce that padding to the least amount necessary for the total number of lines?

I know I could go for a programmatic solution (e.g. piping into `cut` etc), but I'm wondering if there's some sort of switch or configuration parameter I'm ignorant of that controls this behaviour.

Comment: Piping to another command, wouldn't keep the interactive `less` functionality. But you could use `nl -w4 file | less`, (`-w` sets the width for `nl`).

Comment: Fixed in less – https://github.com/gwsw/less/issues/103

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update**

This functionality has been promptly added to Less [in the
form of an extra command line option](https://github.com/gwsw/less/commit/13f1a7d9efe3a017a08bf3666a6da87771734d17), `--line-num-width=N`. The original answer below is valid up to Less version 570, as per the [commit history](https://github.com/gwsw/less/commits/master).

---

**Original answer**

No, there is not an option to reduce the padding. The padding is
done in [the `line.c` file of the source code](https://github.com/gwsw/less/blob/v483/line.c#L195):

```c
/*
 * Display the line number at the start of each line
 * if the -N option is set.
 */
if (linenums == OPT_ONPLUS)
{
    char buf[INT_STRLEN_BOUND(pos) + 2];
    int n;

    linenumtoa(linenum, buf);
    n = (int) strlen(buf);
    if (n < MIN_LINENUM_WIDTH)
        n = MIN_LINENUM_WIDTH;
    sprintf(linebuf+curr, "%*s ", n, buf);
    n++;  /* One space after the line number. */
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        attr[curr+i] = AT_BOLD;
    curr += n;
    column += n;
    lmargin += n;
}
```

The amount of padding is `MIN_LINENUM_WIDTH`,
defined in the header file `less.h` as 7, enough to preserve the
numbers alignment for files with less than ten million lines.
If you find that excessive, you can always change it and recompile.

Comment: Update: as the current maintainer of less himself has commented above, in case someone else sees this answer before that comment: https://github.com/gwsw/less/issues/103